# How to replace Unicode code numbers by UTF-8 characters in a number of files?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, conversion, special-characters

I have 500 files that contain escaped Unicode characters like so:

```
Albert Vel\u00e1zquez
V\u00e9ronique Ekin
```

etc.  The data was queried from a server by a script through `XMLHttpRequest`s and I assume the type of quoting stems from there.

As you can see each `\u00xx` needs to be replaced by the respective special character:

```
\u00e1 -> á
\u00e9 -> é
```

etc.

**Question: How do I replace these code sequences by their respective UTF-8 counterpart, non-interactively within all files?**

The Unicode code points seem to be all 8-bit but it was not possible to check all occurrences (too many).  Perhaps multi-byte characters would be displayed like `\u00xx\u00yy`?  Or perhaps `\uxxyy` if this is some sort of 7-bit clean UTF-16?  I hope someone here recognises the character representation (I could not find it online) and can recommend a script that handles multi-byte sequences correctly.

EDIT:
Please note that `iconv` cannot handle the file format:

```
# iconv --list | wc -l
1179
```

`iconv` knows 1179 encodings.  Just try them all out:

```
# foreach enc ( `iconv --list | tr -d /` )
foreach? echo ==== $enc >> enctest
foreach? echo 'Vel\u00e1zquez' | iconv -f $enc -t UTF-8 >> enctest
foreach? end
# grep -a --before=1 Velázquez enctest
Exit 1
```

The file does not contain the correct string :-(

Comment: I bet the answer will involve `iconv`

Comment: @Stewart Yes, I tried that actually but `iconv` could not handle the format (though the `man` page seemed to suggest it).

Comment: Which shell are you using?. It could be converted  back by a few shells.

Comment: @Isaac Apparently the `tcsh`'s builtin `echo` command cannot do it natively, nor can `/bin/echo` from current GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to parse it through `echo` (or `printf`).

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=
while read -r line ; do
  printf '%b\n' "$line"
  #or: echo -e "$line"
  #or: printf "$line\n"
done <infile >outfile
```

**WARNING**: This method will interpret **ALL** escaped charaters! So it will only work if the **ONLY** occurrences of backslashes are for unicode characters or uniterpretable .

**Example**

```
$file infile
input:  ASCII text
$cat infile
Albert Vel\u00e1zquez
V\u00e9ronique Ekin
DOS Path: C:\data\user\file\u123.txt

$file outfile
outfile: UTF-8 Unicode text
$cat outfile
Albert Velázquez
Véronique Ekin
DOS Path: C:\data\user
                      ileǵ.txt
```

Where `\f` is interpreted as *form feed*, `\u123` as `ǵ`, while `\d` and `\u`(ser) do not have interpretations.

Comment: Thanks, that works well (my file is not very special, no NULs and no other backslashes as these are files with database entries about people). I have incorporated LL3's suggestions (hopefully understood them correctly, feel free to edit).